# Re - Covid-19 - Mandatory vaccination - What's the logic behind not checking for antibodies in individuals before requiring their vaccination?

Tags: covid-19

**The Question**
**Re - Covid-19 - Mandatory vaccination** - In countries with mandatory vaccination, what is the logic behind not checking for antibodies in individuals,  before requiring the vaccination of those individuals ?

- In other words,  why not give individuals who do not want to be vaccinated, the option of having an antibody test first, and using that test to determine if their vaccination is absolutely necessary .

It is regularly mentioned on media that many individuals who have been previously infected, have a higher immunity to being reinfected, or less symptoms .

Comment: You would have to ask the governing officials in those countries what their logic is. This isn't a medical science question; it's a political question. The better question here would be something along the lines of whether antibody-based tests can verify immunity and to what degree. Also, we require questions here to demonstrate some degree of prior research, so you need to provide a source to back up claims like those who were previously infected have higher immunity.

Comment: Should I clarify the question by inserting "what is the medical science logic"  .....................,  which is what I mean by posting the question in 'Medical Sciences' .

Comment: @infomtn No, you can't fix the question by just adding some trivial text like that. The question needs to be about medical science, not the decisions made by politicians. We don't know why they made the decisions they made and whether any of them were based on science at all. And let's get back to the prior research problem. You say it's regularly mentioned in the press that previous infections confer more immunity than... something. Give us an example of such an article. We can't address things we haven't seen.

Comment: To add to @CareyGregory 's last comment - Which press (quote + link please)? Do you know their sources? Are those sources scientifically valid? What's the current scientific consensus on protection via infection and how long that lasts for COVID? - all pretty easily searchable things.

Comment: Carey Gregory :     It’s pretty clear that an implicit premise in this question is that the humoral presence of neutralizing antibodies to a pathogen is highly predictive of immunity. This has been so basic of a concept In medicine for over 50 years now, that no one really talked about it prior to 15 minutes ago when people started making up reasons for you to take this vaccine.  This is a valid question.  And you’re missing the point of it (cause you’re brainwashed). Sorry.  https://www.nature.com/articles/s41591-021-01377-8

Answer (score -4):

There is no good *medical* argument for this.  It's routine with some (pre-CoViD-19) vaccines to [test for antibodies prior to vaccination where patient history is uncertain](https://immunisationhandbook.health.gov.au/recommendations/serological-testing-for-immunity-to-rubella-is-only-recommended-before-or-after), or [after vaccination](https://www.hepb.org/prevention-and-diagnosis/vaccination/) to ensure [non-responders can be revaccinated and retested](https://www.hepb.org/prevention-and-diagnosis/vaccination/vaccine-non-responders/).  With millions who have recovered from CoViD-19, it appears that immunity due to recovery from infection is longer lasting and at least as effective.

If there was such a sound medical argument for this, I think I'd have heard about it, figured it out, or both, or someone will provide one here, as I've seen the question you ask raised many times, and have yet to hear an answer grounded in virology, epidemiology, etc...  Dr Fauci was asked essentially this question on TV and didn't provide an answer.
Sanjay Gupta (CNN) asked Fauci on December 4, with Anderson Cooper (CNN) in frame, about the large Israeli study suggesting natural immunity provides much better protection than the vaccines alone.  Fauci responded that he didn't have a firm answer on that-we (meaning NIH/NIAID) have to discuss the durability.    With millions who have recovered from CoViD-19, it appears that immunity due to recovery from infection is longer lasting and more effective, compared to every vaccine available.[Israeli National Study Reveals Natural Immunity Durability Appears Superior to 2-Dose Vaccination, but Hybrid Immunity Trumps All](https://trialsitenews.com/israeli-national-study-natural-immunity-durability-appears-superior-to-2-dose-vaccinated-durability-but-hybrid-immunity-trumps-all/)
May 2021, a third of the U.S. population, estimated at 44% of adults aged 18-50, had already been infected, suggests Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) data.

Comment: You state that infection provides equally good protection that is longer lasting. You need to provide a citation for that claim.

Comment: It's also rather unusual to test for antibodies before giving a vaccine. It increases cost, delays the vaccine, and in most cases offers no benefit. So your statement that there is no good medical reason could use a citation too.

Comment: First one - sure. Will.  Re the second - Sorry, are you saying the average medical benefit is negative for the vaccines for which it is routine to test for antibodies prior to vaccination?

Comment: Odd.  It seems someone voted this down within seconds of me posting the above comment.

Comment: By May 2021, over a third of the U.S. population, estimated at 44% of adults aged 18-50, had already been infected, suggests Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) data...

Comment: How do we know it increases overall cost?  I doubt it does.

Comment: You believe testing is free? Of course it increases cost. Moreover, it adds another obstacle to mass vaccination. Now people have to come to get a test, then wait days for results, then maybe come back to get a vaccine. The added hassle and time requirement is going to lose millions of people who would have been willing to just come get a vaccine. But you're welcome to prove me wrong with data.

Comment: Also, the link you added is to a media site that provides only a vague description of the study you're actually trying to cite and no link to it. I was able to find what is probably the study you're actually referencing on medrxiv.com, but it took some work and I'm not sure I found the specific study you intended. Can you please find at least a link to the abstract? That media article says nothing useful.